# How do I remove an application?

Tags: software-uninstall

How do I remove an app (Tonido) in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11):

Ubuntu offers several ways to remove an application. For all further explanations I assume that you installed some Ubuntu package. So the explanation is not valid if you installed software via `./configure && make && make install` or used some kind of app specific setup wizard.

### Software-Center

Ubuntus Software-Center (Applications --> Software-Center) lists software which is currently installed on your computer. You can use the search box to look for a specific application. Click on the application you wish to remove and click on the Remove-button.

### Synaptic

Another way to remove software is by using Synaptic. Click on System -> Administration -> Synaptic. A new window open and you can enter some search term into the box. So you will narrow down the list of software. After you found the software to remove right-click on the package and select **Mark for Removal**. Then apply the changes. Synaptic will show you a window with the changes it wants to make and if you apply the software will be removed.

### Aptitude

Aptitude is a text-mode software. You will need to open a terminal and enter `sudo aptitude`. Aptitude shows you a textual interface. You can search for your software by typing a slash (`/`) and entering some part of the name. If the software doesn't show the software in the first place (some packages have similar names) click `n`. If you find the package you want to remove enter `-`. After you found all your software enter `g`. Aptitude will show you all software it wants to remove. If all is correct enter `g` again and the software will be removed.

Aptitude can also be used via commandline. If you know the exact name of the software type:

```
aptitude remove packagename
```

You can also use `aptitude purge packagename`. Aptitude will then remove anything which is related to the software (config files, database files etc.)

### apt-get

`apt-get` is a full command line program. If you want to remove software enter:

```
apt-get remove packagename
```

You can also use `purge` as in aptitude.

Comment: Some apps have windows-like setup wizards, like firefox if you download it from its site or some games.

Comment: shouldn't apt-get come before aptitude?

Comment: @fluteflute: Why do you think so?

Comment: `aptitude` has been removed from the default (Maverick) Ubuntu install (so new users will not have it installed. Those who do have it installed will know they can use it instead of 'apt-get'.

Whilst I prefer `aptitude` and think it is worth including, `apt-get` is certainly the 'official' way to do things.

Answer (score 6):

If you had installed the app through the *normal means*, I mean the Software Centre, synaptic or a .deb file, etc... you need to search for the app in the Software Centre and click uninstall.

You can also uninstall it from the command line using

```
$ sudo apt-get remove appname
```

There are a couple of advanced options, like purging (removing config files) and removing dependencies. You will need to use synaptic or the command line to use them.

If you used some other method of installation, you will need to tell us about how you installed it to be able to help you.

Comment: I installed the app directly from Tonido.com

Comment: Then `sudo apt-get remove tonido` should do the job, if not refer to the tonido support forums at http://www.tonido.com/forum/

Comment: Thanxs...done!!!

Comment: Don't forget to hit the checkmark beside this answer to mark it as correct, namkid.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove tonido
```